# Display @obj#{count} properly in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would i get `<%= "@obj#{count}" %>` to actually display the variable value in the DOM instead of @obj0, @obj1, etc

I've got variable @obj0, @obj1, @obj2, etc that I need to display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of ways.

First, the most correct (IMHO) is to put all your vars to an array and index that.

```
 arr = [@obj0, @obj1, @obj2]

 <%= arr[count] %>
```

Another option is to use `eval`. Avoid this (unless you **really** know what you're doing).

```
<%= eval("obj#{count}") %>
```

Comment: I've just done some reading on eval() and I think I'll probably take your first suggestion.

Comment: But, actually there should be no risk in using eval() as long as you're not evaluating user input? Would you agree?

Comment: @Abram: yes, but it's a slippery slope. :) Better to stay away completely.

Comment: Thanks Sergio for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are going for but I think you want

```
<%= @obj.count %>
```